# Reading XML attributes from a SOAP request to a WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have a MessageContract class with properties with MessageBodyMember attribute set.
The incoming soap request has an XML element, that looks like this:

```
<level num="3">error</level>
```

The property for the error level inside the MessageContract looks like this:

```
[MessageBodyMember(Name="level", Order = 6)]
public string ErrorLevel { get; set; }
```

Instead of the string 'error', I want to read the value of the attribute 'num'. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If you get back an Xml you can load the xml into XDocument and then use Linq to find the appropriate node to get its value and attribute values

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a xml type using this class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx

The code is:

```
TextReader sr = new StringReader("<level num="3">error</level>");
XElement xml = XElement.Load(sr);
```

Once that is done you can access the attributes like so:

```
int Num = Int32.Parse(xml.Element("level").Attribute("num").Value);
```

If you are creating a full xml document you need "XDocument" and "XDeclaration".

Remember the necessary using statements.

Comment: (These are the same LINQ classes Sayak also mentioned)

Comment: *Rajesh also mentioned*... sorry

Comment: Yes, but how can I convert the incoming SOAP request to XElement? VS automatically parses the XML to entities as soon as it received a request.